# Setting filename variable once to be used multiple places

Tags: excel, vba

I have several macros that require the use of the filename so changing them all when the filename changes is a bit of a pain.  I would like to be able to enter it once and have that update everywhere.  I've tried and it fails at the "Windows" callout.

```
Global thisfilename As String

Sub setfilename()
    thisfilename = ThisWorkbook.Name
    MsgBox thisfilename
End Sub
```

and this is where it is failing

```
Sub Copy70io()
'
' copychart Macro
'

    Windows("thisfilename").Activate
```

I'm sure my error is pretty simple but I have no programming experience beyond Google and I haven't been able to figure out how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Try `workbooks(thisfilename).activate`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because your variable is within quotes. And anything within quotes is considered as a string :)

Try this

```
Windows(thisfilename).Activate
```

FindWindow has also given you an alternative.

Here is how I would do it...

Instead of using a Global variable, convert your code to a function. Here is an example

```
Function wb() As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
End Function
```

And then you can use it as

```
Sub Copy70io()
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

Another Example

```
Function wb() As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Blah Blah")
End Function

Sub Copy70io()
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```